# Font Family will still be the same upon pasting different font styles in an editable <div>

Tags: html, css

I have this contentEditable of div.

```html
<div id="article-body" className="content-body" contentEditable={true} spellCheck={true} onKeyUp={this._onChange} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: update_form.body }}>
</div>
```

And this div will look like a text area. So I want that during input, when anyone tries to paste any paragraphs that has different font-family or style, I would like to remain the font-family or style to its default font-family or style depending on how it is being set.

Should anyone could help me with this?

Comment: So you want whatever font-family was being used on the original source to be brought over when pasted into the `contentEditable` element? Also, looks like you're using React, is that correct?

Comment: I mean I want that the font-family of the pasted text will be change into the default font-family set into that contentEditable element to accomplished uniformity of font-family. And yes I am using react.js

Comment: Have you tried defining the `font-family` property for the element?

Comment: Yes I've tried already, but nothing happens, still the `font-family` of the pasted text was being displayed to that element.

Answer (score 0):

I see. One option, which I haven't fully cross-browser tested, would be to use the `input` event, grab the `event.target.innerText` (which is only the text without styling), and then set the `innerText` of the element with that value.

```js
var editable = document.getElementById('editable');

editable.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  editable.innerText = event.target.innerText;
});
```

```css
div {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="editable" contentEditable>Edit me!</div>
```

Comment: it doesn't work in my part. Maybe I got a mistake in implementing it in react.

Comment: Yes, the solution above is not implemented in React, but the solution should be similar. If you can share your React component that would be helpful.

Comment: this `div {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  color: red;
}` can I used it in the id of my editable div?

Comment: Yes, it could be used with an `#` selector to select on the div with a specific id. As in `div#editable {font-family: ...}`

Comment: Hard to help when we can't see your full code. You'll need to update the original question with your complete React component code.